# I'm not getting the right result with this store procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use this store procedure to get the list of test created, but anytime i make a new entry(create a new test) the new entry is not showing on the list.

But i added 2 new columns to Test Table called StartDateTime and EndDateTime

```
USE [School-OnPremise]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CMS_Test_GetList] 
@SubjectId int,
@ProgramId int,
@ProgramLevelId int,
@AcademicTerm int,
@AcademicSession int,
@AddedBy int,
@EntityStatus int = null

AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
select i.*,
  (select Count(*) from TestQuestion where TestId = i.Id) As QuestionNumber,
  (select Count(*) from StudentTests where TestId = i.Id and score is not 
  null) AS ResultsCount
  from Test AS i
  where i.ClassId =COALESCE(@ProgramId,i.ClassId)
  and i.SubjectId = COALESCE(@SubjectId,i.SubjectId)
  and i.Session = COALESCE(@AcademicSession,i.Session)
  and i.AcademicTerm = COALESCE(@AcademicTerm,i.AcademicTerm)   
  and i.AddedBy = COALESCE(@AddedBy,i.AddedBy)  
  and i.EntityStatus = COALESCE(@EntityStatus,EntityStatus)
  order by i.AddedOn desc
END


GO
```

this the table when i execute the stored procedure passing the argument needed i am supposed to get the entries that fall in the category of the arguments i passed.click sql table to see the image below

[sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkQ51.jpg)

When i tried to execute the store procedure this is what i get

```
USE [School-OnPremise]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CMS_Test_GetList]
        @SubjectId = 3142,
        @ProgramId = 2045,
        @ProgramLevelId = 0,
        @AcademicTerm = 1,
        @AcademicSession = 2018,
        @AddedBy = 3,
        @EntityStatus = null

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

this is the ouput i get

[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voKo4.jpg)

[ouput cont.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtNe.jpg)

Comment: You do not provide sufficient information for us to help you. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At a total guess (using my crystal ball for the day): You state *"i added 2 new columns to Test Table "* yet you use `select i.*,`. Unless you have updated the definition of the trigger, the columns returned by `*` won't update. `*`. In  a compiled object, will only return columns at the time it was compiled; and can have some odd behaviour after an object is changed. You should declare **all** your columns, and amend the trigger appropriately with the new columns.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your reply but i have tried that when executing the stored procedure using sql management studio passing the arguments needed  the columns i added usually double up(having 2 columns of StartDateTime and EndDateTime) in the output area

Comment: Can you post the table definition for table "Test"? And update with your current code as it must have been changed to "double up" your output columns... I can't see any way that is possible with the code initially posted. The only way I can think of the 2 new columns "doubling up" is by adding them to the select list along with *.

Comment: @Allumearz yeah you are right i was including the columns in the select list, but i'm not still getting the result i want. Hold on a sec i will post something now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, your final condition is testing i.EntityStatus = NULL - this will not work - if a column value = null then it will only satisfy the IS NULL operator.

```
and (@EntityStatus IS NULL OR (@EntityStatus IS NOT NULL AND i.EntityStatus = @EntityStatus))
```

Comment: I am assuming here that EntityStatus values in the database are currently NULL - I cannot see that column value in your screenshot... Please correct me if the values are something other than NULL.

Comment: yes the entity status is null, thanks a lot for your time, I've seen the problem not the stored procedure the problem from my code. At the point of creating a test, I was not saving the value of the entitystatus. it is when editing a test the value of the enititystatus will be saved because it is was only added in the form for the edit page

Comment: @Timothy: not even a +1 or accepted answer?! I answered your question as to why your stored procedure was not returning the expected result. If you had replaced the condition in the SP, it would have returned all the rows you expected, including the NULL values in EntityStatus. If the EntityStatus should never contain NULL, then it should be declared as a NOT NULL column - then your program would have failed when trying to insert NULL - highlighting your initial problem and not a red herring!

Comment: i'm sorry about the +1 thing i don't really post question on stack overflow so i didn't know i was suppose to do that. Anyways i just accepted your anwer but i cannot change the 0 to +1 i don't know why. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not the test procedure, it  from the code below there is nothing saving the enitystatus' value

```
    public bool insert_New_Test(string TestName, int Duration, int SessionYear, int ClassId, int SubjectId, bool Status, int AddedBy,
                int ProgramLevelId, int AcademicTerm, int questionSetUpType, out int id, DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, int? testType)
            {
                bool functionReturnValue = false;
                id = 0;
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand oComm = new SqlCommand();
                        using (oComm)
                        {
                            oComm.Connection = con;
                            oComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            oComm.CommandText = "CMS_Test_Insert";

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                            oComm.Parameters["@Title"].Value = TestName;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SubjectId", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@SubjectId"].Value = SubjectId;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClassId", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@ClassId"].Value = ClassId;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Session", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@Session"].Value = SessionYear;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProgramLevelId", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@ProgramLevelId"].Value = ProgramLevelId;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AcademicTerm", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@AcademicTerm"].Value = AcademicTerm;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Duration", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@Duration"].Value = Duration;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit));
                            oComm.Parameters["@Status"].Value = Status;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AddedBy", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@AddedBy"].Value = AddedBy;


                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionSetupType", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@QuestionSetupType"].Value = questionSetUpType;

                            if (startDateTime > DateTime.MinValue)
                            {
                                oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                                oComm.Parameters["@StartDateTime"].Value = startDateTime;
                            }
                            if (endDateTime > DateTime.MinValue)
                            {
                                oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                                oComm.Parameters["@EndDateTime"].Value = endDateTime;
                            }

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestType", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@TestType"].Value = testType;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.Bit));
                            oComm.Parameters["@Success"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                            oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", SqlDbType.Int));
                            oComm.Parameters["@TestId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            oComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            functionReturnValue = Convert.ToBoolean(oComm.Parameters["@Success"].Value);
                            id = Convert.ToInt32(oComm.Parameters["@TestId"].Value);

                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                    functionReturnValue = false;
                }
                return functionReturnValue;

            }
```

so when it try to get the value for the entitystatus the value is null

```
public List<TestViewModel> get_List_Of_Test(int SubjectId, int ProgramLevelId, int AcademicTerm, int AcademicSession,
            int ProgramId, int status)
        {
            List<TestViewModel> sList = new List<TestViewModel>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand oComm = new SqlCommand();
                    using (oComm)
                    {
                        oComm.Connection = con;
                        oComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        oComm.CommandText = "CMS_Test_GetList";

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SubjectId", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@SubjectId"].Value = SubjectId == 0 ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : SubjectId;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProgramId", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@ProgramId"].Value = ProgramId == 0 ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : ProgramId;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProgramLevelId", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@ProgramLevelId"].Value = ProgramLevelId == 0 ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : ProgramLevelId;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AcademicSession", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@AcademicSession"].Value = AcademicSession == 0 ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : AcademicSession;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AcademicTerm", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@AcademicTerm"].Value = AcademicTerm == 0 ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : AcademicTerm;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AddedBy", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@AddedBy"].Value = MembershipHelper.GetActiveUser().Teacher.IsAdmin ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null : MembershipHelper.GetActiveUserId;

                        oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EntityStatus", SqlDbType.Int));
                        oComm.Parameters["@EntityStatus"].Value = status;

                        SqlDataReader rdr = oComm.ExecuteReader();
                        if (rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            int _sn = 0;
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                int publicStatus = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "EntityStatus");
                                _sn++;
                                TestViewModel qList = new TestViewModel();
                                qList.ProgramLevelId = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "ProgramLevel");
                                qList.ProgramLevelText = Extensions.ListEnums.GetProgramLevel().Skip(qList.ProgramLevelId - 1).First().Text;
                                qList.AcademicTermId = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "AcademicTerm");
                                qList.AcademicTermText = Extensions.ListEnums.GetTermChoice().Skip(qList.AcademicTermId - 1).First().Text;
                                qList.TestTitle = _rdrHelper.GetOrdinalStringValue(rdr, "Title");
                                qList.ClassId = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "ClassId");
                                qList.ClassName = _rdrHelper.GetOrdinalStringValue(rdr, "ClassName");
                                qList.SubjectName = _rdrHelper.GetOrdinalStringValue(rdr, "SubjectName");
                                qList.SessionId = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "Session");
                                qList.TestId = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "Id");
                                qList.Duration = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "Duration");
                                qList.Status = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalBooleanValue(rdr, "Status");
                                qList.QuestionCount = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "QuestionNumber");
                                qList.TestSn = _sn;
                                qList.ResultExists = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "ResultsCount") > 0;
                                qList.AddedBy = _rdrHelper.getOrdinalInt32Value(rdr, "AddedBy");
                                qList.Test.StartDateTime = _rdrHelper.getNullableOrdinalDatetimeValue(rdr, "StartDateTime");
                                qList.Test.EndDateTime = _rdrHelper.getNullableOrdinalDatetimeValue(rdr, "EndDateTime");
                                qList.Test.EntityStatus = publicStatus;
                                sList.Add(qList);
                            }
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
```

one my create page there is no field to pass the value for the entitystatus

[create test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeFQ4.jpg)

but for the edit page there is a field to pass value into the entitystatus

[edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdoL4.jpg)

the publish status is the field that gives the entity status value. The thing is after creating the test i'm redirected to the edit page to click the save button so that all entries will be saved into the databas3 but i did not click the save button i just went back to the index page which shows the list of tests.